# Pygame update display

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a program where sensors(the white circles) are moving on the map to cover things. I counted the number of covered things(the small white dots), it's the right number. But the old covered things and sensor(white circles) are still on the screen. How can I update the display so that only newest objects are on the screen(no red dots should be in the circle path, and the circle path history should not be displayed).[image: My display]

Here is my display code. It gets called every frame.

```
    def _drawMap(self,ticks):
    # draw the map
    # draw the boundary
    boundary = self._polygonCoordinationTransformation(self.data.boundary_polygon_list)
    pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, BLUE, boundary, LINEWIDTH)

    # draw obstacles
    for polygon in self.data.obstacles_list:
        polygon = self._polygonCoordinationTransformation(polygon)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, BLUE, polygon, LINEWIDTH)

    # draw agents
    self._executeSegment(self.agentsGroup.sprites()[0],(5,10),ticks)
    for agent in self.agentsGroup:
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, WHITE, agent.rect.center, self.data.sensor_range * self.scaleForMap,LINEWIDTH)

    # draw items
    self.updateUnseenItems()
    for itemObj in self.unseenItemGroup:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, RED, itemObj, LINEWIDTH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pygame you can't clear the screen - instead you re-blit the background back over the top of what is currently there.

There's an excellent answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257865/how-to-clear-up-screen-in-pygame).

Edit: In your case you probably want to fill the screen in with black:

```
screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
```

Comment: Thank you! I added this as the first line of  function in the qustion, and now it's working properly.